# How to execute query that will separate by certain symbol in Repository Springboot using java

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to separate the result data with query by `"~"` within the same entity, to separate another entity data by `","`

**My code**

**mainRepository.java**

```
public interface mainRepository extends CrudRepository<Error, Long> {

    @Query(value= "SELECT * FROM Error t where t.applicationID = :applicationid", nativeQuery= true)
    List<Error> findListByApp(@Param("applicationid") String applicationid);
}
```

and in another class I call that function

```
String cb = errorRepository.findListByApp("application1").toString();
System.out.println(cb);
```

the result if i execute cb is

```
[com.info.main.Error@6ec8b40e, com.info.main.Error@6ec8b40e, com.info.main.Error@6ec8b40e]
```

I want to keep it sorted by app first, then name, then email.

the result that i want to achieve is just like this :

```
[app1~name1~email1, app2~name2~email2, app3~name3~email3]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are using toString with the result List?

```
String cb = errorRepository.findListByApp("application1").toString();//why toString?
```

Instead you have to use a List like so :

```
List<Error> result = errorRepository.findListByApp("application1");
//this will print the list or Error it will call to String for each error
System.out.println(result);
```

to show the result you need just override `toString` method in your Error entity with the format you want for example.

```
@Entity
public class Error {

    private String app;
    private String name;
    private String email;

    //getter setter

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return app + "~" + name + "~" + email;
    }
}
```

Comment: i just change it to List<Error> result = errorRepository.findListByApp("application1"); as you said and then i print it with result.toString() . but still got the same error

Comment: what did you mean @user_22?

Comment: no dont print `result.toString()` print just the list like so `System.out.println(result);` check my edit

Comment: I just add the @Override toString as you mentioned in your edit and it works. thank you